# how to get value of dl tag HTML from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select the following value from the HTML file either by Jquery or Javascript.
`Bank Transfer`, can some one suggest me how can i do.

```
<div class="color-me" id="txnDetails">
  <div class="panel-apply-font-size">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cols">
        <dl class="entityDetails-field">
          <dt>PaymentMethod</dt>
          <dd>Bank Transfer</dd>
        </dl>
      </div> <!--end of cols-->
      <div class="cols">
        <dl class="entityDetails-field">
          <dt>AccountNumber</dt>
          <dd>34343</dd>
        </dl>
      </div> <!--end of cols-->
      <div class="cols">
        <dl class="entityDetails-field">
          <dt>BankName</dt>
          <dd>Bank Of America</dd>
        </dl>
      </div> <!--end of cols-->
    </div><!--end of rows-->
  </div><!--end of panel-->
</div><!--end of color me-->
```

I was doing like this:

```
$("#txnDetails dd").on(function(){
    $(this)....
});
```

here I don't have any class-names nor ID tags given for `DT` , `DD` elements, how can I get to the first DD tag to pick it's text? I want the text of first DD tag that is value "Bank    Transfer".

Comment: try `$(#txnDetails dd:first).text()`

Comment: `on` what? What's the user event you're interested in? `click`, `hover`? can you be just a bit more precise? Whave you googled or explored SO on "how to get first children element of-type?" or anything similar?

Comment: On a side note your HTML seems exessive, there is a lot of nesting going on there. Do you really need an entire `div` to apply the style `panel-apply-font-size`? Are you aware you can apply more than one classto an element? E.g for your top div could be `<div class="color-me panel-apply-font-size" id="txnDetails">`. Do you really need the `col` divs? You probably could remove those and just use the `dl`s for your colums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
$('#txnDetails dd:first').text()
```

or

```
$('#txnDetails').find('dd').first().text()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the :nth-child() selector:

```
$("dd:nth-child(1)").text();
```

You only need to know the position the element you are targeting is in.

Required Reading:

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
 $("#txnDetails dd").first().text()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the values with:

```
$('#txnDetails dd:first-child').val();
```